# JPA service layer transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have MVC layered app using JPA 2, Hibernate (without Spring or any additional framework).

Now transactions are achieved only on DAO layer like this:

```
public class AccountDao {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public AccountDao(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    public void saveAccount(Account account) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            em.persist(account);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But what I want is to obtain transaction on service layer:

```
public class AccountService {
    private AccountDao accountDao;
    private UserDao userDao;

    //needed the method to be in transaction
    public void transferUserAccount(){
        User user = // ...
        userDao.saveUser(user);

        Account account = //
        accountDao.saveAccount(account);
        //rest logic that has to be executed atomically
    }
}
```

One of possible solution is to wrap code inside `transferUserAccount()` method in another `try/catch/finally` with  `em.getTransaction().begin()`
(or create custom @Transactional annotation that will do that under the hood), but I am not sure how JPA handles nested transactions.
Also such solution exposes the DAO specific things like entity manager 
into service layer.

Anyway, is the solution with nested transaction within `transferUserAccount()` is appropriate?

Are there any other solutions to handle such cases?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would assume that there is a one-to-may correlation between users and accounts, am I correct? When this is true, you can add an appropiate cascade-type to the user-attribute within the account object to save/update the corresponding user when an accoutn is saved/updated.

Comment: @Turing85 yes you are right, but there are also other things that should be performed atomically. Th question is how to achieve transactionality in service layer using plain jpa without spring

Comment: If you do not want to leak the transaction management into your service, I would suggest to further split the DAO such that the DAO has two DAOs/repositories-attributes (one for `User`, one for `Account`), create the transaction in the DAO-method and pass it down to the `User`- and `Account`-DAO/repository.

Comment: @Turing85 You mean to pass `EntityManager` explicitly to all dao methods that should be done in one transaction?

Comment: What are the reasons not to use spring framework? I've wrote once my own custom transaction annotation, but this is no fun at all.

Comment: @Reni yes, exactly.

Comment: @ManuelPolacek Spring does actually not help. Even if you were able to use `@Transactional`, you would still have to add an additional layer to define which methods create the transaction and which one requires it.

Comment: But with this Transactional annotation you could even start new Transaction, also if another one already exists. In my eyes it is very flexible. I haven't had issues with it until now. (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html).

Don't get me wrong, i just want you to show you the flexibility of spring transaction. If you just don't want to use spring this is something different. But as i've said, own custom transaction annotation is not easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to leak the transaction management into your service, I would suggest to further split the DAO such that the DAO has two DAOs/repositories-attributes (one for `User`, one for `Account`), create the transaction in the DAO-method and pass the `EntityManager` down to the `User`- and `Account`-DAO/repository.

Another option would be to create a method `transferAccount(Account account, user from, user to)` within `AccountDao`, create the `transaction` there, perform all your logic and then call `userDao.save(from, em)`, `userDao.save(to, em)` and `save(account, em)` from there.